# iText: Unable to select radio button

Tags: itext

I have a pdf with few radio buttons:

[image]

I want to select one of them programmatically using iText:

```
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdf, true);
Map<String, PdfFormField> fields = form.getAllFormFields();
PdfButtonFormField german = (PdfButtonFormField)(fields.get("german-language"));
german.setRadio(true);
```

But resulting pdf doesn't have the radio button selected.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using the wrong method. The `setRadio(...)` method is defined as:

> If true, the field is a set of radio buttons; if false, the field is a
> check box. This flag should be set only if the Pushbutton flag is set
> to false.

So you are basically using a method which makes the field a radiobutton.
You should try:
`german.setValue("german");`

Since we don't have the PDF the value "german" can be different. Check the PDF for that...

**Update:**

In the Pdf it is the name of the appearance e.g.

`/N<</german 98 0 R/Off 99 0 R>>`
The structure should look like this:

```
//The Parent Object aka radio button group
4 0 obj
<</FT/Btn/Ff 49154/Kids[97 0 R 102 0 R 107 0 R]/T(language)/V/german>>
endobj

//child 1
97 0 obj
<</AP<</N<</german 98 0 R/Off 99 0 R>>>>/AS/german/BS<</S/I/W 1>>/F 4/MK<</BC[0.0]/BG[1.0]/CA(l)>>/P 19 0 R/Parent 4 0 R/Rect[502 770 515 781]/Subtype/Widget/Type/Annot>>
endobj

//child 2
102 0 obj
<</AP<</N<</french 98 0 R/Off 99 0 R>>>>/AS/Off/BS<</S/I/W 1>>/F 4/MK<</BC[0.0]/BG[1.0]/CA(l)>>/P 19 0 R/Parent 4 0 R/Rect[522 770 535  782]/Subtype/Widget/Type/Annot>>
endobj

//child 3
107 0 obj
<</AP<</N<</english 98 0 R/Off 99 0 R>>>>/AS/Off/BS<</S/I/W 1>>/F 4/MK<</BC[0.0]/BG[1.0]/CA(l)>>/P 19 0 R/Parent 4 0 R/Rect[540 770 553 782]/Subtype/Widget/Type/Annot>>
endobj
```

You can try the method `public String[] getAppearanceStates()` and see what it returns.

Comment: Thanks for input. So basically what value do we pass to setValue()? I mean what exactly shoud I look for in PDF?

Comment: @Mandroid See my updated answer. If you find the relevant part in the PDF add it to your question...